# Can't serialize an object

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I defined a model like this

```
public class Planilla
{
    [Key]
    public int IDPlanilla { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [Display(Name = "Dirección de Negocio")]
    public int IDDireccionDeNegocio { get; set; }

    [Required (ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public bool Activo { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual DireccionDeNegocio DireccionDeNegocio { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a method in my controller that returns the first element of this model

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetElements(string IDCampana)
    {
        Planilla query = db.Planillas.First();
        return Json(query);                 
    }
```

My problem is when I invoke this method from client side throws an error that say's

> circular reference is detected trying to serialize
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Planilla_7F7D4D6D9AD7AEDCC59865F32D5D02B4023989FC7178D7698895D2CA59F26FEE
>   `Debugging my code I realized that the object returned by the execution
>   of the method`First`it's a`
>   {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Planilla_7F7D4D6D9AD7AEDCC59865F32D5D02B4023989FC7178D7698895D2CA59F26FEE}
>   `instead a Model of my namespace like`
>   Example.Models.DireccionDeNegocio`.

Why am I doing wrong?? Because I tried with other models and work's well

Comment: Can you provide a test snippet that highlights your error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use view models, that's the only advice I can give you. Never pass domain models to your views. It's as simple as that. And if you respect this simple rule and fundamental rule in ASP.NET MVC applications you will never have problems. So for example if you need only the id and the description in your view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetElements(string IDCampana)
{
    Planilla query = db.Planillas.First();
    return Json(new 
    { 
        Id = query.IDPlanilla, 
        Description = query.Description 
    });
}
```

Notice that in this case the anonymous object serves as view model. But if you really wanted to do things properly you would write your view model:

```
public class PlanillaViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetElements(string IDCampana)
{
    Planilla query = db.Planillas.First();
    return Json(new PlanillaViewModel 
    { 
        Id = query.IDPlanilla, 
        Description = query.Description 
    });
}
```

By the way Ayende wrote a [nice series of blog posts](http://ayende.com/blog/4806/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-a-broken-home-controller) about this.

Comment: I have a question here: Why we add 2 more properties of the same in the VM as we already defined in our domain model.

Comment: @klm9971, we do this because that's what this particular view (JSON object) will need. Another view might need other properties. So we would define another view model for it. You should always define specific view models for each view. Think of the view as a projection of your business entities. So a view model is simply a projection of the domain model.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.*` is the Entity Framework proxy namespace. Your `DbContext` creates your entities as such to support lazy loading and change tracking. This isn't your problem. The problem likely lies in a circular association.

Comment: And I agree with @Darin Dimitrov, use view models.